# PHP / начало. калькулятор

Tags: php, denwer

даны кнопки ПЛЮС И МИНУС

2 строки числа

кнопка РЕЗУЛЬТАТ

строка с Результатом

как написать,чтоб после того как я ввел 2 числа,нажал ПЛЮС,мне выводилось то же самое(то есть формы заполнены,кроме результата), но php понял,что я Нажал плюс, а лишь потом НАЖИМАЮ результат и выводиться РЕЗУЛЬТАТ в СТРОКУ (type="text")?

Comment: Я когда начинал `*`овнокодить, мне и в голову не приходило делать калькулятор... имхо не лучшая практика!

Answer (score 1):

Надо данные, которые пришли из формы обратно вставить в форму.

```
if(isset($_POST['a']) && isset($_POST['b'])){?>
   <input name='a' value='<?=$_POST['a']?>'>  
   <input name='b' value='<?=$_POST['b']?>'>  
<?}
```

P.S.: a,b - это имена слагаемых, подставьте свои имена вместо них.

Answer (score 1):

"но php понял,что я Нажал плюс..."
Боюсь, что здесь должен понимать не PHP, а Вы должны понимать как происходит взаимодействие клиентской и серверной частей приложения.

PHP скрипт примет переменную (со знаком сложения, вычитания и т.д.) и если у него нет дальнейших инструкций, весело и непринужденно завершит свою работу, забыв все, что ему там передавали. Соответственно необходимо эту переменную либо как-то сохранить (сессия, БД и т.д.), либо отдать обратно пользователю на экран и учесть при повторном запросе.

Как определить, что был нажат именно "ПЛЮС", а не расчет результата, тут просто:

```
<form action="test.php" method="POST">
  ...
  <p><input type="submit" name="action" value="+"></p>
  <p><input type="submit" name="action" value="-"></p>
  <p><input type="submit" name="action" value="рассчитать"></p>
  ...
</form>
```

Форма может содержать несколько кнопок типа "submit", и при нажатии на определенную кнопку она передаст именно свое значение. То есть, если в данной форме будет нажата кнопка "+", в скрипте "test.php" значение $_REQUEST['action'] будет равно "+"; если будет нажата кнопка "рассчитать" - $_REQUEST['action'] будет равно "рассчитать" и т.д.

Ну, как понять какое именно было действие я рассказал. Остальное сами.

Критику ответа приветствую.

---

И это все при том условии, если вообще есть необходимость известить сервер заранее о предстоящих манипуляциях с числами. В противном случае, знак можно подставлять с помощью js в скрытое поле и отправлять на сервер непосредственно при нажатии кнопки "рассчитать".